# The title-starting-with-tag block doesn't work if there is no space after it

Tags: bug, feature-request, tags, warning-message

I stumbled upon a question (no, I'm not linking it here to avoid the Meta Effect) that has a title like this "[TAG ]Some error message". That isn't a very good title, but after [testing it out myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73451981/javascripttest) (link for 10k+, screenshot below), I realized that the thing to block tags doesn't work if there is no space after the tag.

Can it be updated to still issue the message if there is no space?*

[image]

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100494. Note the first comment by Stu pointing out the issue :)

Comment: @cigien I did read that, and I think it makes sense, but... blocking titles that are error-dumps isn't a terrible side effect IMO as they are poor titles anyways. Might need a link to ["How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)", but if that was added I don't think blocking `[ERROR]Something didn't work` is a bad effect, especially given that the overall goal IMO is to have good titles

Comment: To clarify, I don't think your proposal is a bad idea. I was referring to Stu's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/disallow-square-brackets-in-question-titles-opened/100494#comment255376_100494) explaining why the currently implemented regex requires a space after the tag.

Comment: Yeah well, the User should re-read their Thread Title and realize there is an obvious Typo in `[TAG ]Some...` (The Space is misplaced...) + Also a Typo in your Post @OP in `spcae`... // Typos everywhere, =>no wonder "you" get "unexpected" Results... // = "Syntax Error" for most Runtime Engines... :idea: // EDIT; `spcae` quickly corrected in the 5min Edit time for a Comment.... Good...!